# Are the unit vectors in the cylindrical and spherical coordinate system constant vectors with respect to a rectangular coordinate system?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, vectors, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

Are the unit vectors in the cylindrical and spherical coordinate system constant vectors w.r.t. a rectangular coordinate system?

Answer (score 1):

If you write your spherical coordinate unit vectors in terms of rectangular Cartesian coordinates,

\begin{align}
\hat{\mathbf r}
&=\sin \theta \cos \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf x} +
\sin \theta \sin \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf y} +
\cos \theta \,\hat{\mathbf z}
\\[5px]
\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}
&=\cos \theta \cos \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf x} +
\cos \theta \sin \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf y}
-\sin \theta \,\hat{\mathbf z}
\\[5px]
\hat{\boldsymbol\varphi}
&=-\sin \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf x}
+ \cos \varphi \,\hat{\mathbf y}
\end{align}

the answer to your question should be clear.
A similar exercise can be done for cylindrical coordinates.

[A useful pdf about coordinate systems?](http://web.mit.edu/8.02t/www/materials/modules/ReviewB.pdf)